# GitHub client cannot sync after changes made to some files

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have a git repository in which I work in collaboration with some people but I cannot sync anymore. I am using the GitHub Windows client application on Windows 7:

1. Last time I synced, the operation succeeded and I ended up with a perfect copy of the latest code.
2. Next, I made some simple changes to a few files, but did not commit anything yet.
3. In the meantime, someone else made changes to some other files.
4. In order to see the changes of the repository, I'm trying to sync again.
5. GitHub client reports "Sync failed".

Now I am wondering if this is normal behavior or if there is something wrong with my repository ? Shouldn't I be able to sync the repository and get latest files even though I am making some changes that are still not committed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you got this kind of error just try to open a git shell and type `git status` into your working directory. You will have some infos that could help you like which files are in conflict.

It must be one of the other collaborators that updated and pushed a file you just updated. If so, you will have to choose which version you want to keep in your local files.

Comment: Interesting comment, but if there is such a file that was edited by both a collaborator and myself, will the GitHub client manage to merge both versions and notify of any conflicts or I need to use the git shell and do it manually?

Comment: Actually i prefer resolving conflicts through the command line and don't use Github Desktop that much, so i'm not 100% sure but if you manage to find these files you should see the conflicts markers.
I can't really help you with the use of the desktop software but to the best of my knowledge, command line is the most powerful way to find conflicts.